# Unity map generation mesh doing weird things

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So for some reason, this map generation works for up to xSize=100 and zSize=100.

As soon as I go further it does weird things like this (at xSize=300 and zSize=300):

[image: underside of the mesh]

Going even more up to 1000x1000 it generates something like this:

[image: Generation with 1000x1000]

I have no idea why it works just up to 100x100.

Is there some mesh limitation I'm not aware of?

I first thought just the vertices weren't connecting properly but then after doing the 1000x1000 example and looking the 300x300 example from top it definitely doesn't even make the vertices in right place...

I can't see an error in my code for some reason. I'm stuck here looking the code blindly all day.

Any help?

Code [Just the CreateMapXZ() function]:

```
vertices = new Vector3[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];
uvs = new Vector2[(xSize + 1) * (zSize + 1)];
float uvFactorX = 1.0f / xSize;
float uvFactorZ = 1.0f / zSize;

for (int i = 0, z = 0; z <= zSize; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x <= xSize; x++)
    {
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(x, 0, z);

        uvs[i++] = new Vector2(x * uvFactorX, z * uvFactorZ);

        //i++;
    }
}

triangles = new int[xSize * zSize * 6];

int vert = 0;
int tris = 0;
for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
    {
        triangles[tris + 0] = vert + 0;
        triangles[tris + 1] = vert + xSize + 1;
        triangles[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
        triangles[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
        triangles[tris + 4] = vert + xSize + 1;
        triangles[tris + 5] = vert + xSize + 2;

        vert++;
        tris += 6;

    }
    vert++;
}

applyNoise();
UpdateMesh();
```

Comment: When you go from 100x100 to 300x300, you [start exceeding Unity's default mesh vertices limit of 65535](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.IndexFormat.html). Can you try to set `mesh.indexFormat = IndexFormat.UInt32;` somewhere at the beginning to see if it fixes your issues (also, add `using UnityEngine.Rendering;` at the top)? It will now allow 4 billion vertices. Good luck!

Comment: For use more than 65535 vertex mesh you need to add extra submesh or change mesh.indexFormat to 32 bits how Philipp Lenssen mean. Calculate your vertex and divide by 65535 to know how many submesh you need.